# download .doc not working but open on a same browser why

Tags: php

download .doc  not working but open on a same  browser why

```
if ($stmt->execute(array($userID))) 
{
$stmt->execute();
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header('Content-type: text/plain charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.doc');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
$username=htmlspecialchars($row['userName']);
<table width='90%' height='60%' align='center' border='1' dir='rtl'>

download .doc  not working but open on a same  browser why
```

Comment: Could you explain yourself please?

Comment: export.doc is name  file download in php page get result from query when click button to downlod file . file open in the same brwser not force download  as attachment as dialoge box